# possible to transition outline color with css3

Tags: html, css

Is it not possible to transition outlines with css3?

```
body{margin:10px;padding:0px;}
#tDiv{
    background-color:#999;
    width:500px; 
    height:500px;
    color:black;
   outline: 5px dashed #222; 
    -moz-transition: color 2s;
    -o-transition: color 2s;
    -webkit-transition: color 2s;
    transition: color 2s;
    -moz-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out;
    -o-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: outline-color .7s ease-out;
    transition: outline-color .7s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .7s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color .7s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .7s ease-out;
    transition: outline-background .7s ease-out;   
}
#tDiv:hover{
    color:green;
    background-color:gold;
    outline: 5px dashed magenta;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/uKGCc/

This just changes the outline immediately..

Thanks

​

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UF3Ht/5/ `transition: all ...;` seem to work in Safari and Firefox

Comment: @biziclop it also works in FF

Comment: @biziclop awesome! can you submit that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: That's not the solution, the last `-*-transition` rule will be applied, try reordering those rules.

Comment: @biziclop I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to apply multiple different transitions, you have to coalesce them into one rule (plus repeat them with the necessary prefixes):

```
-webkit-transition: color 2s, outline-color .7s ease-out, background-color .7s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: color 2s, outline-color .7s ease-out, background-color .7s ease-out;
     -o-transition: color 2s, outline-color .7s ease-out, background-color .7s ease-out;
        transition: color 2s, outline-color .7s ease-out, background-color .7s ease-out;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UF3Ht/6/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition-property

```
transition:
   [<'transition-property'> || <'transition-duration'> || <'transition-timing-function'> || <'transition-delay'> 
[, [<'transition-property'> || <'transition-duration'> || <'transition-timing-function'> || <'transition-delay'>]]*
```

When you use the same property multiple times, only the last one will be applied as usual:

```
transition: outline-color .7s ease-out;    /* this will be overridden */
transition: background-color .7s ease-out; /* this will be used */
```

Comment: "you have to coalesce them into one rule" <-- Critical save there buddy, thank you!